# Fluid Simulation will not fill entire simple cube

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am trying to animation cement being poured into wooden framework to construct a column. Domain is surrounded by separate play wood objects. Domain flush up against the play wood but does not fill entire domain. I've looked into the Manifold situation and no vertices seem to be selecting to cause it to me non manifold. Are the other objects surrounding the domain causing this?

[image: Left is Domain object, right is max width fluid will fill.]

Comment: Does increasing the resolution cause it to get closer to the edge of the domain?

Comment: @JtheNinja Currently set to 125. Making 250 and baking.. we shall see.

Comment: @JtheNinja Okay it seems like it does make that fluid fill up more.. Still trying to calculate the resolution i need to get it to fill entirely. 200 made it very close... 350, still not flush up against edge of domain.

Comment: Another thing to look at is the scale of the domain and source objects. If one of these isn't set to `1`, it will throw off the simulation. Apply the scale if necessary with `Ctrl` + `A`.

Comment: Changed everything.. Made the actual Domain transparent and a lot bigger and made the old Domain an invisible "Obstacle." This simulates the fluid MUCH better thatn creating the Domain as the column.. @ScottMilner Everything was already set to a scale of 1. And JtheNinja your suggestion did not solve it exactly how i wanted it to.. Thank you to both of you